# DateRange client side validation in ASP .NET6 using Fluent Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, fluentvalidation, client-side-validation

In my application I'm using a form to enter user information including birthdate. I want to perform both client-side and server-side validation and I'm using Fluent Validation.

I want a clean solution and have choosen not to use build-in validation using attributes. Everything works as expected but not client-side InclusiveBetween (or a combined GreaterThanOrEqualTo/LessThanOrEqualTo). Server-Side validation works as expected.

**Input DTO:**

```
public class PersonDto
{
    // properties omitted

    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

    // properties omitted
}
```

**Custom Validator for PersonDto**

```
public class PersonDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<PersonDto>
{
    public PersonDtoValidator()
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-100);
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;

        // Rules omitted

        RuleFor(person => person.BirthDate)
            .InclusiveBetween(start, end)
            .NotEmpty();

        // Rules omitted
    }
}
```

**Generated Html**

(sorry for the Danish language in the validation message):

```
<div class="form-floating mt-1">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="date" data-val="true" data-val-range="&#x27;Birth Date&#x27; skal v&#xE6;re mellem 21-04-1922 00:00:00 og 21-04-2022 00:00:00." data-val-range-max="04/21/2022 00:00:00" data-val-range-min="04/21/1922 00:00:00" data-val-required="&#x27;Birth Date&#x27; b&#xF8;r ikke v&#xE6;re tom." id="Person_BirthDate" name="Person.BirthDate" value="1988-03-12" />
    <label for="Person_BirthDate">Birth date</label>
</div>
<span class="text-danger small field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Person.BirthDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

**Use of InclusiveBetween**

I have tested using `InclusiveBetween` on properties of other types as i.e. `long`. Client-Side validation works as expected.

**Use of nullable `DateTime`**

Changing from `Datetime?` to `DateTime` has no effect.

**Any Ideas?**

To my eye everything looks fine and i'm left frustrated. Hope anyone can help?
I'm using .Net6 using the standard Razor Page Template and corresponding Jquery assembly (no changes made).
FluentValidation v10.4.0

### Update!

Some have speculated RangeAttribute not to support `DateTime` according to official documentation, `DateTime` is supported.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=net-6.0

This leaves the issue being related to `jQuery.validate.unobtrusive` library. Have any one got the library to perform client-side validation of a `DateTime` `RangeAttribute`?

Comment: Could be a JavaScript date parsing issue, I'm seeing 3 formats in your example html; MM/DD/YYYY (04/21/2022 00:00:00), DD/MM/YYYY (21/04/1922 00:00:00), and YYYY-MM-DD (1988-03-12). Date.parse("21/04/1922 00:00:00") returns NaN.

Comment: Oopss. My mistake. I manually corrected the date format. See latests edit for correct format in the HTML.

Comment: The DateTime values in the markup is auto generated by Fluent Validation and there seems to be no way to control the format.

Comment: The client side validation is not performed by FluentValidation, but rather a JavaScript library (I think it's the jQuery validation plugin, sorry don't know off hand). Based on what you're saying - that it works with other types - I'd be questioning whether the JavaScript library supports date range validation OOTB. Greater than/less than validators are not supported client side, you've got to write your own (https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#clientside-validation).

Comment: I must admit I'm not used to working with JQuery. Any suggestions on where to find inspiration to create my own validation plugin?

That said it seems strange Microsoft does not provide support for client-side validation of DateTime Range as the documentation states is is supported.

Comment: Microsoft isn't providing the client side validation. The support will be server side in the HTTP request pipeline, it'll validate the model as part of receiving a request. I used this blog https://ml-software.ch/posts/extending-client-side-validation-with-fluentvalidation-and-jquery-unobtrusive-in-an-asp-net-core-application as the starting point for creating my own adapters.

Comment: Honestly, client side validation is a PITA. My preferred approach is to write all of the validation at the service layer, then use an AJAX request to perform the validation. No adapters and no validator limitations.

Comment: I fully agree it is a PITA. Sodfarvede my solution is to removed validation of date range on the DTO and then adding a simple validator before checking ``ModelState``. It is entirely for user expirience as I doing a full validation when mapping data into entities in the service laver.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your page:

```
@section Scripts{ 
    //......  
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}   
}
```

Then it will work well

[image]

=============================

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-floating mt-1">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="date" data-val="true" data-val-range="&#x27;Birth Date&#x27; skal v&#xE6;re mellem 21-04-1922 00:00:00 og 21-04-2022 00:00:00." data-val-range-max="04/21/2022 00:00:00" data-val-range-min="04/21/1922 00:00:00" data-val-required="&#x27;Birth Date&#x27; b&#xF8;r ikke v&#xE6;re tom." id="Person_BirthDate" name="Person.BirthDate" value="1988-03-12" />
    <label for="Person_BirthDate">Birth date</label>
    <span class="text-danger small field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Person.BirthDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">submit</button>    
</form>


<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the cause.
I have included _ValidationScriptsPartial (though not async, but using ``<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />``)

Comment: When you use `F12` to check the html in browser, Is there any error message about jquery in console?

Comment: No errors in the console.
I have a "Mixed content" warning, but this is not related to this issue.

Comment: It's very stange, `client side validation` is related to js not FluentValidation, If the `js` can be loaded in the correct order and then the verification is successful, I have add something in my answer.

Comment: Xinran>> Can I ask you to run your test again, but this time enter a valid date?
I have investigated further today and it seems even data annotations doesn't work with jquery.
``[Range(typeof(DateTime),"2000-01-01", "2022-12-31")]`` both fails for dates within or outside allowed range.

Comment: I tested again and found a very strange phenomenon, no matter if the time I selected is within the range or not, when I click submit it will appear `'Birth Date' skal være mellem 21-04-1922 00:00:00 og 21- 04-2022 00:00:00.` and prevent me from submitting the form.

Comment: So far I have created a workaround and removed validation of BirthDate from the model, and then created a separate server-side validation extension method. It provide the requested output, but requires a round trip to the server before user feedback is given.